# is there a developer api for pandora on android?

Tags: android, api, pandora

I was looking around but couldnt find one, was wondering if anybody knows of such an api?
basically I want to be able to switch songs and play songs on pandora from my application on android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no api from pandora available.

Answer (score 0):

Unofficially there is actually:

http://pan-do-ra-api.wikia.com/wiki/Json/5

This is the JSON version

Answer (score 0):

As of KitKat you can use the RemoteController class to control andy media play that has a registered client like Pandora.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html

Answer (score 0):

There is.
https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/

But I've read that Pandora changes it up sometimes to discourage people from writing their own (probably ad-free) clients, so there's no guarantee that it will last.